# xml LinearLayout different behaviours

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-xml, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a custom button layout. I created an xml file "custom_button.xml" which I then inflate in the "ButtonLanguageSelection" class. In this class I added the onClickListener. I added this class to the "main_activity.xml". It behaves like it should except it won't receive any touch events. Then I copied the code from "custom_button.xml" and added it directly without inflating it, I just added the android:onClick parameter and in this way it worked. I can't find out what would be the problem, the layouts are the same.

Has some of you have similar problems? What could be the problem? I attached the code if it helps someone to find the problem.

Thank you for any help!

custom_button.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/button_language_selection_states"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:clickable="true"
          >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_select_language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="30px"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textColor="#333333"
/>

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="10px">
</View>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="40px"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ButtonLanguageSelection

```
public class ButtonLanguageSelection extends LinearLayout
{

private TextView introductoryTextView;
private TextView language;


private final String TAG = "ButtonLanguageSelection";

public ButtonLanguageSelection(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ButtonLanguageSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button_language_selection, this);


    introductoryTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_select_language);
    language = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_language);


    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onclick");
        }
    });
}

public ButtonLanguageSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setIntroductoryTextView(String s)
{
    introductoryTextView.setText(s);
}

public void setLanguage(String s)
{
    language.setText(s);
}
```

}

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/screen_welcome_bg">

<defaultpackage.ButtonLanguageSelection
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLanguageSelection_Slovene"
        android:layout_width="341px"
        android:layout_height="260px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"/>

<defaultpackage.ButtonLanguageSelection
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLanguageSelection_Italian"
        android:layout_width="341px"
        android:layout_height="260px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"/>

<!--<defaultpackage.ButtonLanguageSelection-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/ButtonLanguageSelection_English"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="341px"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="260px" />-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="341px"
              android:layout_height="260px"
              android:background="@drawable/button_language_selection_states"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:onClick="sendMessage"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_select_language"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="30px"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            />

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="10px">
    </View>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_language"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="40px"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is writing all the init code in only one constructor. Consider making an init function and call it from all the constructors. Also consider setting the onClick events listeners in your activity rather than than the layout constructor itself.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I wrote the init function and I call it in all constructors. I also set the onClick listener in the activity, but unfortunately the result is the same.